# Why jsp can't find attribute from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can't transfer attribute `list` from servlet to jsp.Here's my code:

searchInfo.java:

```
public class searchInfo extends HttpServlet {
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/students" + "?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8" + "&useSSL=false";

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String sql;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Map> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Class.forName(context.getInitParameter("JDBC_DRIVER"));
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, context.getInitParameter("USER"), context.getInitParameter("PASS"));

        sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION WHERE id=?";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, req.getParameter("id")); //get id from form
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        toList(rs, list);

        req.setAttribute("list", list);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/search2jsp.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if(pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req, resp);
}

static void toList(ResultSet rs, List<Map> list) throws SQLException {
    while(rs.next()) {
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String sex = rs.getString("sex");
        int age = rs.getInt("age");
        String college =rs.getString("college");
        String major = rs.getString("major");
        String phone = rs.getString("phone");

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("name", name);
        map.put("sex", sex);
        map.put("age", age);
        map.put("college", college);
        map.put("major",major);
        map.put("phone", phone);

        list.add(map);

        for(Map map1 : list) {
            System.out.println(map1);
        }

    }
}
```

}

search2jsp.jsp

```
<html>
```

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Students Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Search Students Information</h1>
    <table align="center" width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>sex</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>college</th>
            <th>major</th>
            <th>phone</th>
        </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${list}" var="usr">
                <tr>
                    <td>${usr.id}</td>
                    <td>${usr.name}</td>
                    <td>${usr.sex}</td>
                    <td>${usr.age}</td>
                    <td>${usr.college}</td>
                    <td>${usr.major}</td>
                    <td>${usr.phone}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

but it shows `Cannot resolve variable 'list'` in search2jsp.jsp

Comment: Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte `Cannot resolve variable 'list'` in code `<c:forEach items="${list}" var="usr">`

Comment: Okay so something then is wrong with the variable you are settings. I reckon it's because it's not a list of items. Please edit your post and include more java code.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Thank you. I have already added my code into my question.

Comment: Hi Friend Use JSTL Library Using following imports and refer JSTL in google Search
and JSTL Only works with DTO Since You have not Used it hence 
`ClassObj.Proprty` will not work.

`<%@taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

Comment: @AvijitBarua Yes, I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. Here's the way:

1. Add `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` to the project dependencies
2. Add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>`
   at the beginning of the jsp file.